# Data models in php

Tags: php, database, datamodel

I'm sort of experimenting with very obscure data models in php. For example, if I have a table called "model_attributes" in an SQL database. This is a list of all the available attributes for the model I'm working on. Now, I want the model, and other models to be able to derive functions from this list to pull data out of an array, after the data has been loaded into the array from the constructor. Here is an example in pseudo-code:

```
for each attributes as attribute
    create new function ( getAttributeName )
```

and

```
getAttributeName()
```

would

```
return $this->_model_data['attribute_name']
```

First off, is this good practice? It seems organized, but at the same time seems kind of dirty. Maybe someone could give me some other suggestions as to how to handle large data models in php.

Also, if anyone has done something like this, how could I handle this in phpDocs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not be able to do this easily at runtime with PHP.

You may use an existing ORM, for example [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/).

Or you could pre-generate the model class files, or use [magic methods](http://php.net/__call).

Quick example:

```
class something {

    private $_model_data;

    public function __call($name, $value = null) {
        if (strpos($name, 'get') === 0) {
            $attribute = substr($name, 3);
            return $this->_model_data[$attribute];
        } else if (strpos($name, 'set') === 0) {
            $attribute = substr($name, 3);
            $this->_model_data[$attribute] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

`__call` is a magic method that gets called when the method does not exists. So, calling `getAttributeName` on an instance of the class would call `__call` with the string `getAttributeName` as first argument.

Comment: Specifically, the `__get` method from that URL you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the array of `model_data` from the context of a container object, you should use either the [`__get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) magic method, or implement the [`ArrayAccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface.

`__get` is the easy way out as the implementation would look something like this:

```
function __get($name)
{
  if (array_key_exists($name, $this->model_data))
  {
    return $this->model_data[$name];
  }
  return;
}
```

To access the data you'd just call the property of the object: `$obj->property_name`, or in the case where you're using a string: `$obj->{$property}`
Of course, this may interfere with any public attributes you have (generally a bad idea to have them anyway).

Alternatively you can set up your object as an implementation of ArrayAccess, which will allow you to access the property as: `$obj['property_name']`, or `$obj[$property]`

Both solutions will allow you to have custom access management, if you want to obfuscate your field names, or adjust how the data is retrieved later.

AFAIK the ArrayAccess method is faster, but you'd have to test it to be certain. Magic methods have a tendency to be a bit slow.

Comment: yes, I agree. What I've decided to do is, generate a base list of attributes for each model that have defined methods and use __get as a way of accessing attributes that aren't part of the direct model, i.e. custom attributes.